# Why was this edit rejected by the author?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I am trying to figure out where I went wrong with this edit:

[image]

link: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28586398

I noticed that `if` was misspelled (the OP's question was about `if` statements, so I decided to edit it and remove that "Thank You"  while I was at it)

It was rejected because

> The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing.

So I can learn and improve, can someone point out what is wrong with this edit?

Comment: 1. Why do you think that you did anything wrong? 2. It is the author's prerogative to accept or reject any edits to their posts, regardless of reason. It's probably best to simply move along.

Comment: From my own point of view, the only *significant* change that you made to the post was to change `of` to `if`. All the other changes are just fluff.

Comment: I don't think you did anything wrong. The edit comment could be better since the edit doesn't just add "code fences", but other than that, the edit looks good.

Comment: We can only guess. Only the post owner can answer this question.

Comment: Your edit is good, it strictly improves the post. The author was incorrect to reject the edit. You can of course just move on, but you can raise a mod flag explaining the issue if you want.

Comment: Both question and answer will be deleted within days at most, so it's probably best to focus your efforts elsewhere in any case.

Comment: The answer should just be deleted.  The author of the answer didn't even bother to put code in their answer, to a question, that contained code.  The question itself has some serious formatting problems.

Comment: As someone active in the suggested edits queue, I think your edits were mostly beneficial (not sure about some of the formatting, but that's not a big deal). Please, do continue removing fluff from posts and improving formatting. That said, I would save the effort for posts that are worth it (hint: new users are also less likely to appreciate edits to "their" posts as they think).

Comment: @SecurityHound I wasn't aware that answers had to contain code.

Comment: @VLAZ - The answer is clear as dirt.  Code would have clarified it.

Comment: @SecurityHound counterpoint, wouldn't have helped *this* answer. A *good one* wouldn't really need code. A great one might but wouldn't rely on it to be comprehensible.

Comment: Please only use code format for code, not for isolated words/tokens just because they do or could appear in code. If an author has done so, best to keep the same style when editing. PS "code fence" is usually used for the style of block code format on SO, not for backquoted inline code.

Comment: @philipxy: Yeah, looks like the formatting was unequivocally inappropriate for the words list, set and tuple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They rejected both of your edits and approved someone else's. God knows why. Maybe they didn't like you removing their thank-yous (people from their culture tend to say thank you in answers for reasons I can't comprehend). Maybe they didn't like you making such drastic changes to their grammar (another thing the other person didn't do). Maybe they felt targeted by your actions and were acting in self-defense. Maybe they just didn't like your kind, or were put off by your anonymity. Last sentence facetious — I don't think Tim Post losing his keys would have anything to do with it.

In any case, your edits were fine, and should not have been rejected on those grounds.